# Use two Key Events one after another in C#

Tags: c#, keyboard, increment

I have 3 text-boxes in my C# Windows Form application for A, B and C respectively. Just like a simple scoring board.

What I want to do is when I press 'A' and then '1' the value in the text-box below should increment by 5 and when I press 'B' and then '1' the same should happen with the text-box below B and same as 'C'.

Just remember I don't want to use the combination keys. Below is the code for your reference:

```csharp
private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D1 || e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad1)
        {
            int vA = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            vA += 5;
            textBox1.Text = (String)vA.ToString();
        }
    }

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.B)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D1 || e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad1)
        {
            int vB = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            vB += 5;
            textBox2.Text = (String)vB.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to first press A, B or C, and then afterwards press a number, then you cannot nest those if-statements like you did. First you check if the current key pressed is "A", then in the same scope you check if the current key pressed is "1", which can never be.

Comment: @PranavPatel I see no problem with his request. yes he is asking for help.

Comment: @PranavPatel His english is probably the reason why he asked his question like he did. I'm sure you can relate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you do NOT want to use combination keys, what you want to do is something similar to this (probably clean it up a little bit).

```
TextBox target;
private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
    {
        target = textBox1;
    }

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.B)
    {
        target = textBox2;
    }

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D1 || e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad1)
    {
        if(target != null)
        {
            int vA = int.Parse(target.Text);
            vA += 5;
            target.Text = (String)vA.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use a member variable to keep the value of last pressed key and use that variable inside KeyUp method to check the conditions.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Keys lastkeyPressed = Keys.Enter;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (lastkeyPressed == Keys.A)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D1 || e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad1)
            {
                int vA = 0;
                int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out vA);
                vA += 5;
                textBox1.Text = (String)vA.ToString();
            }
        }

        if (lastkeyPressed == Keys.B)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D1 || e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad1)
            {
                int vB = 0;
                int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out vB);
                vB += 5;
                textBox2.Text = (String)vB.ToString();
            }
        }

        if (lastkeyPressed == Keys.C)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D1 || e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad1)
            {
                int vC = 0;
                int.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out vC);
                vC += 5;
                textBox3.Text = (String)vC.ToString();
            }
        }
        lastkeyPressed = e.KeyCode;
    } 
}
```